# Absolutely continuous with jump discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that If a function is absolutely continuous then it has not any jump discontinuity?

Comment: If a function is absolutely continuous, then it is continuous, so it has no discontinuity...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Absolute continuity $\Rightarrow$ continuity hence no jump or any discontinuities.

Comment: This answer would be improved if instead of "Yes" you said "Absolutely".

Comment: @Yakk I'm hoping this is a joke (in which case it's hilarious) otherwise I don't get it X_X

Answer (score 3):

Every absolutely continuous function is uniformly continuous and, therefore, continuous.